# Spring MVC @RequestMapping for anything before the "/url"

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

Let say I have the code below:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edituser/{id}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable int id) {
        return "usereditform";
    }  

    @RequestMapping("/thankyou")
    public String thankyou() {
        return "thankyou";
    }
```

When I go from the edituser page to thankyou page, the url ends up being [/edituser/thankyou] which is gives me

```
HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
```

So how do I make it so that as long as the url contains "/thankyou", it will be handled by the controller.

What I mean: "asdnwnafmasnd/thankyou" should lead to thank you page as well as "home/profile/editprofile/thankyou"

**Edit:** 
I am currently using a workaround using multiple mapping:

```
    @RequestMapping("/thankyou")
    public String thankyou() {
        return "thankyou";
    }
    @RequestMapping("edituser/thankyou")
    public String thankyou() {
        return "thankyou";
    }
```

This workaround is less than ideal as it requires a new mapping for every new page created.

**Edit 2:** 
For more information, I am using dispatcher servlet like so (in web.xml):

```
    <servlet>    
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>      
    </servlet>    
    <servlet-mapping>    
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I am also using view resolver like so (in spring-servlet.xml):

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">    
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>    
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>    
    </bean>
```

So I have my jsp files under /WEB-INF/view/ named as "thankyou.jsp", when the controller returns "thankyou", user will see the thankyou.jsp page.

**Edit 3:** 
The pages are called using href:

```
<a href="thankyou">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: `@RequestMapping` takes an array of paths, so you can just do `@RequestMapping({"/thankyou", "edituser/thankyou"}`. However the issue isn't your mapping as the result handling/url generation which is relative instead of absolute. You should be fixing that instead of adding URLs all around your codebase.

Comment: I didn't know @RequestMapping takes array, thank you. Can you elaborate on relative instead of absolute url? Which one should I use for large projects? Also, how/where can I learn to implements this. If you could point me in the right direction I would deeply appreciate it. I am **required** to use SpringMVC.

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you are sending it to the thankyou page. So on where and how to solve is impossible to answer currently.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for telling me. I have added some extra information, I hope this can help clarify how my code is working, if there is more information I could provide, please do tell.

Comment: @Nor It will be also good if you can share  code how you are calling the "thankyou" page. say <a href="thankyou">Click Me</a>

Comment: I still don't see where your code, eventually, leads to that thankyou page.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am not sure what you mean. `@RequestMapping` returns a string which correspond with my jsp file name, if the specified file is present, it is served to the user, so it will lead to thankyou page when the url is "myserver/projectname/thankyou" in my case localhost:8080/XYZPortal/thankyou would lead to the thankyou page. What I want is for localhost:8080/XYZPortal/[anything]/[randomthing]/thankyou to also lead to thank you page

Comment: Use a wildcard mapping `/**/thankyou` but not sure why you want that.